# mySQL update all column fields only if all column fields are = something

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Sorry if this is not clear, but ill try my best to make it as clear as possible.

so basically i want to update all column records if all column records are = something.

For Example:

```
Name   id  Col1  Col2
Row1   1    6     1
Row2   2    2     1
Row3   3    9     1
Row4   4    16    1
```

If all Col2 records = 1 then set them all to = 2

So the table is gonna update to this:

```
Name   id  Col1  Col2
Row1   1    6     2
Row2   2    2     2
Row3   3    9     2
Row4   4    16    2
```

But if the table is like this:

```
Name   id  Col1  Col2
Row1   1    6     1
Row2   2    2     1
Row3   3    9     1
Row4   4    16    2
```

Nothing is gonna change, since not all of the records of Col2 are = 1.

I'v got this code, which i know exactly why it does't work the way i want it, but i don't have enough knowledge to fix it:

```
UPDATE test as test, 
(
    SELECT test.Col2 FROM test WHERE test.Col2 = '1'
) as temp
SET test.Col2 = '2' WHERE temp.id = test.id
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bit of a tricky one. Instead of using simple comparisions you will have to use counts

```
UPDATE test, 
(SELECT COUNT(*) as c1 FROM test where Col2=1) as a1, 
(SELECT COUNT(*) as c2 FROM test) as s2 
SET test.Col2=2 WHERE c1=c2;
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thanks alot, i really do appreciate it.

Comment: Glad to have helped